Java with JPA and vectorscale: SQL Error [42704]: ERROR: type "vectorscale" does not exist
I'm building a prototype ML system using Postgres-based extension vectorscale. It goes as follows:
I use a docker image timescale/timescaledb-ha:pg17

I've created a table for embeddings:
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS products.products_embedding (
embedding_id int8 NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
"text" varchar(255),
embedding vector(3072),
metadata json
);

I've installed a vectorscale extension:
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS vectorscale CASCADE;


That all worked well and I can see the extension created:
SELECT * 
FROM pg_extension; - that lists my `vectorscale` and `vector` extensions

Now, when I try to query the db, using Java JPA repository, as in:
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "SELECT * FROM products.products_embedding ORDER BY embedding <=> cast('[:embedding]' as vectorscale) LIMIT :limit")
List<ProductsEmbedding> findByEmbedding(List<Float> embedding, int limit);

, that blows in my face with the following error:
SQL Error [42704]: ERROR: type "vectorscale" does not exist
I get the same result if I plain query in Postgres:
SELECT *
FROM products.argos_products_embedding
ORDER BY embedding <=> cast ('[0.002165521029382944,..(truncated for brievety)..]' as vectorscale)
LIMIT 10;

Why the extension is not found?
BTW, it works if I try
SELECT *
FROM products.argos_products_embedding
ORDER BY embedding <=> cast ('[0.002165521029382944,..(truncated for brievety)..]' as vector)
LIMIT 10;

I have had the 'vectorextension installed earlier on on the same container, and I believe vectorscale is built on top ofvector`, so that works in Postgres.
It still doesn't work in Java though:
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "SELECT * FROM products.products_embedding ORDER BY embedding <=> cast('[:embedding]' as vector) LIMIT :limit")
List<ProductsEmbedding> findByEmbedding(List<Float> embedding, int limit);

Still breaks complaining that ERROR: type \"vector\" does not exist\n  Position: 95
Any idea why the extensions are only found half the time, please?
